# Is there a way to get a link to FTP error log using a shell script?

Tags: bash

I have written the following shell script to transfer CSV file to an FTP server,after successful transfer the script sends an email to client attaching the same CSV files if transfer is successful.What I need is that if the transfer gets failed,then I should attach the FTP error log in the email content.Could anyone please help me on this matter?

```
echo open demoftp.zx >> ftp.txt
echo user demouser pass678 >> ftp.txt
echo lcd /var/www >> ftp.txt

for filename in *csv; 
 do
  echo "put $filename"
done >> ftp.txt

echo bye >> ftp.txt
ftp -in < ftp.txt
rm ftp.txt

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; 
 then
  echo 'Transfer is not successful'
 else
  echo 'Transfer is successful'
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: No, please edit your question and post your example there. See [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why not capture the log by modifying the line  `ftp -in < ftp.txt >xfer.log` and then include `xfer.log` with your failed e-mail.

Comment: Can I assign this xfer.log to a variable so that I can pass that variable to a PHP script?